# 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'jQuery' is undefined - MVC 4

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to get a really simple modal dialog running. So following a tutorial I end up with this code:

BundleConfig:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.js"));
```

_Layout:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")

</head>
<body>
   <div id="body">
        @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
        <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
            @RenderBody()
        </section>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
                <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET MVC Application</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>


    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

and Index:

```
@section featured {
<section class="featured">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <hgroup class="title">
            <h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
            <h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
        </hgroup>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 300,
                width: 350,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {

                    Cancel: function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    }
                },
                close: function() {
                    allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
                }
            });

            $( "#create-user" )
              .button()
              .click(function() {
                  $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
              });

        </script>

        <div style="float: left; width: 250px;">
            <button id="create-user">Create new user</button>
        </div>

    </div>
</section>
}
```

However when I run it I end up with 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'jQuery' is undefined, inside the jquery-ui library. If I simply put the code in an html page it works as expected. So the problem comes from the MVC project. I am using visual studio 2012 on Windows 8. Any thoughts?

Comment: can you show us how the <head> is being rendered after you run it

Comment: In the browser, look at the actual `script` elements generated. You'll probably find the path to the jQuery script is off in some way.

Comment: only the <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.js"></script>
 appears in the head.

Comment: but as you can see the jquery-ui and jquery are imported in the same way ... then way jquery is missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default, the MVC bundler ignores files with `.min` in the filename.

Use the un-minified version of jQuery to fix the problem (or just rename the file) - when deployed, the bundler will minify the jQuery file anyway.

---

**Update**

You can change this behavior by clearing the `IgnoreList` in the `RegisterBundles` method (but I recommend sticking with the defaults and simply renaming the files):

```
// Clear all items from the ignore list to allow minified CSS and JavaScript 
// files in debug mode
bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();    

// Add back the default ignore list rules sans the ones which affect minified 
// files and debug mode
bundles.IgnoreList.Ignore("*.intellisense.js");
bundles.IgnoreList.Ignore("*-vsdoc.js");
bundles.IgnoreList.Ignore("*.debug.js", OptimizationMode.WhenEnabled);
```

See more in the [Telerik docs](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/introduction).

Comment: if I do that I end up with `Exception was thrown at line 5288, column 6 in http://localhost:53886/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError`

Comment: Have you changed the path in the `BundleConfig' file too and rebuilt the project?

Comment: yep now jquery appears in the head element

Comment: Great - updated my answer to show how to change this behaviour.

Comment: If only I'd seen this yesterday.

Answer (score 10):

The problem I ran into when getting this error was due to the fact that the following statements were not in the `<head>` of the document, but just before the `</body>` tag at the end of the document.

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
```

Once I moved them to the `<head>` of my .cshtml file, everything worked fine.

Comment: +1 because this helped me. I had to remove the @Script.Register in the Layout.cshtml file and include it in the cshtml file I'm working in.

Comment: The default layout for a MVC project is to put the scripts.render section near the bottom of the body like this.

Answer (score 5):

Just use @section scripts around your scripts like so

```
@section scripts
  {
   <script>
    $(function () {



        });

    });

  </script>
}
```

Comment: This seems to work & be more elegant, of course, be ware of having two different ones in the same file!

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this one for about an hour, almost all the solutions come down to the order and method which you call your scripts. I found the **bundlers were causing problems** (for me it was the ui bundler)

Here is the order which worked for me.

```
    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.5.3.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script src="/bundles/jquery-ui"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

IE has an other syntax-checking in javascript, than Edge, Chrome and Firefox.
I got same error in my code, when the BundleOptimization was turned on in my MVC application.
I use AngularJS as framework, and one line screwed up the whole bundle, and made an cascading effect:

```
$http.post('/controller/action', { dto })
```

Removing the curly brackets {} - solved my 'missing JQuery-problem'. But that I first found by debugging in the IE (pressing F8 in debug-mode):[image]
The JQuery-error message is misleading, but the syntax-error refers to the right line, so I could fix the error.